# XSLT in Visual Studio

Tags: xslt

Problem with prefix xsl in xslt file:

I'm running the following Code in Visual Studio (along with an .xml and .cs) to transform the xml file to html.

I am having compile errors with this xslt file, I maybe missing a using or nuget package (I've added the Saxon & xslt ViewEngine Packages).  Can anyone please provide some help?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
<xsl:param name="transformDateTime" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>DocumentList</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>
        Transform DateTime: <xsl:value-of select="$transformDateTime"/>
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="FetchDocumentList.Response">
  <ol>
    <xsl:attribute name="style"> color:green </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Document"/>
  </ol>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Document">
  <li>
    <h1>
      <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
    </h1>
    <h4>
      ID: <xsl:text></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>

      : Class:
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="DOC_CLASS"/>
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>

      : Document No:
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="DOC_NUMBER"/>
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>

      : Revision:
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="REVISION"/>
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>

      <xsl:text></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>

      <xsl:text></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>

      <xsl:text></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>

    </h4>

  </li>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Would you include the compile errors?

Comment: there is no other comments when I run it other than "XSLT compile errors", that's all that displays in the console window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the `xsl:stylesheet` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

and close it at the end of the entire document:

```
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks so much..  the </xsl: stylesheet> at the bottom really helped, however when I start without debugging the console window is still telling me theres an XSLT compile error... and no other information is given.  Any more ideas on this?

Comment: "*Any more ideas on this?*" No, not without further information. It runs fine for me, both here and on: http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqp You need a better testing tool.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've just got it working now, I appreciate your help. All the best :)